# Python: Call a variable from a function to an if statement

Tags: python, function, variables

I am trying to practice my modular programming with this assignment. I found out how to call the variables into my main function, but for my if statement in evenOdd(), I am not sure how to call the value. I get the error 'randNum' is not defined.

```
from random import randint
def genNumber():
    randNum = randint(0,20000)
    print("My number is " + str(randNum))
    return (randNum)

def inputNum():
    userNum = input("Please enter a number: ")
    print("Your number is " + str(userNum))
    return (userNum)

def evenOdd():
    if randNum%2==0:
        print("My number is even")
    else:
        print("My number is odd")
    if userNum%2==0:
        print("Your number is even")
    else:
        print("Your number is odd")

def main():
    randNum = genNumber()
    userNum = inputNum()
    evenOdd()
    input("Press ENTER to exit")


main()
```

Comment: `randNum` is out of the scope of `evenOdd()`

Comment: @MooingRawr How would I edit this to make it in the scope? I'm assuming it will be similar to how I did it in main(), but I am not sure how to go about implementing it.

Comment: @TannerBritt You can pass its value to the functions that use its value.

Comment: @TannerBritt Pass the value as an argument to the function. `evenOdd(randNum)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either define randNum in the global scope or just pass it as a variable to your evenOdd() function, like this evenOdd( randNum ).

Comment: Thank you! I originally tried this but got an error for not converting userNum to an int. I stupidly ignored the error thinking it was due to my attempt at a solution.

Comment: type casting will get your every time especially in untyped languages. It's far easier to miss the conversion.